# gauss curve in R, resizing the x axis to SD

Tags: r, plot, histogram, gaussian

I would like to plot a histogram and resize the x axis to Standard Deviation (SD) value. If I plot just:

```
hist(df)
```

The X axis show the real values.

[image: My histogram]

The SD of these values is = 0.38. I would like to convert X axis to SD size, then -1 SD in histogram is equal to -0.38.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x, col='red', xaxt='n') # exclude x-axis

# manually specify axis
m <- c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)
s <- m*sd(x)
l <- paste(m,'SD')
l[4] <- '0'
axis(1, s, l)
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to resize the plot, considering the average instead 0 in the center? It is possible?

Comment: Do something like change `s <- m*sd(x)` to `s <- mean(x) + (m*sd(x))` and change `l[4] <- '0'` to `l[4] <- 'Mean'`, or similar.